# How to create nxn matrix with specific entry value

Tags: r, matrix, cell

How to create a nxn matrix where value in cell `(i, j)` is defined as `1/(i+j-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute-force solution:

```
create_matrix <- function(n){
 m <- matrix(NA, n, n)
 for (i in 1:n){
   for (j in 1:n){
     m[i,j] <- 1/(i+j-1)
   }
 }
 m
}

create_matrix(2)

   [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  1.0 0.5000000
[2,]  0.5 0.3333333
```

You can also use the fact that the resulting matrix is symmetric (but I don't think this is faster):

```
create_matrix_sym <- function(n){
 m <- matrix(NA, n, n)
 for (i in 1:n){
   for (j in 1:i){
     m[i,j] <- 1/(i+j-1)
   }
 }
 m[upper.tri(m)] <- m[lower.tri(m)]
 m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer` to create such kind of matrix, i.e., `M <- 1/(outer(1:n,1:n,"+")-1)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `.row` and `.col` functions. (works for R 3.5.0 or later)

```
n <- 3L

i <- .row(c(n, n))
i
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    2    2    2
#> [3,]    3    3    3


j <- .col(c(n, n))
j
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]    1    2    3
#> [3,]    1    2    3


m <- 1/(i + j - 1)
m
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
#> [2,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000
#> [3,] 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000
```

For earlier R versions:

```
n <- 3L

i <- row(diag(n))
j <- col(diag(n))

m <- 1/(i + j - 1)
```

Comment: It would be fair to mention that `.row` and `.col` entered the `base` package in R 3.6.1

Comment: @slava-kohut To be more precise, starting from 3.6.1 `dim` argument of `.row` and `.col` may also be an integer-valued "double". But thanks for this, didn't know this won't work in earlier versions. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @slava-kohut sorry, they are indeed quite new. Looks like they entered the `base` in 3.5.0 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.5.0/NEWS.R-3.5.0.html